# Submit lots of jobs in a SHELL script

Tags: slurm, sbatch

I am using a simple shell script to read and write lots of files (more than 300 files) in a HPC and I want to submit it using slurm.

The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=40
#SBATCH --exclusive

for in_file in ${in_files}; do
    # do something with ${in_file} and ${out_file}
    echo ${in_file} ${out_file}
done
```

I may not submit all my tasks at one time because the number of files are larger than the nodes I can use. So is there a better way I can deal with the large number of files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the files totally independent? It sounds you could make a bash script that schedules a job for each file and passes it to each job. One way would be to as a environment variable.

Something like

```
#!/bin/bash
for in_file in ${in_files}; do
    export in_file=${in_file}
    sbatch slurmjob.sh
done
```

Where your slurmjob.sh is something like

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -n 1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
 
do something with ${in_file} and ${out_file}
echo ${in_file} ${out_file} > somefile.txt
``
```